# Install El Capitan OS on a new SSD without USB driver

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I have a hard disk and I would like to install an SSD on my MacBook.
However I don't have any USB driver for installing El Capitan OS.

Is it possible to install the SSD and then install El Capitan OS when I use it for the first time? (install after first turning on the computer)

Answer (score 2):

No, you need disk or USB stick to install it.

Why can't you use a USB stick? If that's because you can't buy it from Apple Store, you could use any 8GB+ stick to install drive.

It's very simple, you only need an `Install OSX *version*.app` file and a USB stick.

### Prepare stick

1. Plug it into your MacBook
2. Open Disk Utility (Launchpad -> Other)
3. Choose your stick in left hand side (It should be under `External` label)
4. Click on Erase button at top
5. Choose `GUID Partition Map` under `Scheme`, `OS X Extended (Journaled)` under `Format`, and name it `OSXInstall` (You can give it any name, but you'll need to change terminal commands too)
6. Click on Erase

   [image: Disk Utility]

### Get OSX Installer App

For El Capitan open [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1018109117?mt=12) link, and download it (You may need to click on `View in Mac App Store`

You **do not** need to **install** it, just download.

### Create bootable installer

1. Be sure to check that stick is plugged in and shows up in Finder.
2. If you have no password, set it temporarily
3. Open Terminal app (Launchpad -> Other)
4. Copy and paste this text into Terminal and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/OSXInstall --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
   ```
5. Type you password (It would be hidden, and cursor would not move)
6. Now just wait till it says `Done.`

### Installation

To boot from the installer stick, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key during Mac system start, and select it from the startup volume menu.

Comment: Or use disk maker X. It's automated.